# PHPMailer Timing out

Tags: php, apache, timeout

It would appear that the `PHPMailer` is starting to time out. I have not changed anything, and I started noticing it today. It use to work fine, but now in my `httpd` log I am getting the following:

```
[Wed Mar 04 11:45:44.404291 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5700:tid 140655682516736] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client X:59521] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

It takes a good 60 seconds to timeout - It should not take this long to send the email. Any ideas?

I am using the PHPMailer from git and tried following this example:
http://tecadmin.net/send-email-using-php-script-from-smtp/

I am confused because this use to work fine. Anyone have any ideas on what I should check?

Comment: Do you use SMTP? If so try enabling `SMTPDebug` set the value to 2. It should then echo out what it's doing on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was timing out while trying to connect to the port on the remote SMTP server. This timeout was causing the script to exceed the wait time. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Styphon for the help.

I turned on SMTPDebug and it looks like it was timing out while trying to connect to the port on the remote SMTP server. This timeout was causing the script to exceed the wait time.